# When is the 'post_content_filtered' column in database cleared by WordPress?

Tags: posts, database, post-content

Some WordPress plugins (although very few) use the `post_content_filtered` column in database to save some data related to a post.

For example, [Markdown on Save](http://wordpress.org/plugins/markdown-on-save/) stores the markdown version of a post separately in the `post_content_formatted` column and the parsed HTML in the `post_content` column, so that when the plugin is deactivated the posts won't spew out Markdown (because HTML is stored in `post_content`).

Now, I came to realize that `post_content_filtered` is pretty much used for temporary storage i.e. the content in the column is lost (or cleared) when:

- you make changes to a post (title, tags, categories, etc.) using the 'Quick Edit' option
- a scheduled post is (automatically) published
- you do bulk edits to posts
- you switch between revisions of a post
- a post is saved from an external editor (i.e. not the WordPress post editor)

**Questions:**

1. In what other situations is the data in the `post_content_filtered` column cleared?
2. Is there a way to prevent this from happening at all? (I mean, is there a way to make sure that the data is stored permanently, the way the `post_content` column is treated?)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Every post update in WordPress is handled by the `wp_update_post` function.

This function has some defaults, and for `post_content_filtered` the default value is '' (empty string).

Once the defaults are merged with args passed to function via `wp_parse_args` it means that every time a post is updated and `post_content_filtered` is not explicitly passed, it is set to a empty string.

Now we can ask: when is the `post_content_filtered` explicitly passed to `wp_update_post`? Answer is: *never* by WordPress.

So for your first question:

> In what other situations is the data in the post_content_filtered
>   column cleared?

Short answer is: **every time a post is updated, for any reason**.

Note that changing only one field *is* an update, in particular, every status change is an update, e.g. draft to publish, pending to publish, future to publish, publish to trash (a post delete), and so on...

If something changes in a post, then `post_content_filtered` is cleared; only exception is when `post_content_filtered` is explicitly passed to `wp_update_post`, and as already said, this is never done by WordPress.

> Is there a way to prevent this from happening at all? (I mean, is
>   there a way to make sure that the data is stored permanently?

If you create that field with your code, and you want to preserve it, you have to look at **every** update performed by WordPress, and prevent the change.

This can sound like hard work, but if you read the first sentence in this answer, "*Every post update in WordPress is handled by the `wp_update_post` function*", you understand that the only thing needed is to look at that function, which luckily has different hooks.

The hook that I suggest is the `wp_insert_post_data` for 2 reasons:

- It runs *before* the update, so you don't have to *recover* but you
  can *prevent*
- It passes 2 parameters: the data that function is going to update, and an
  array of the passed parameters, that (in case of update) contain the ID of the post

So using a simple `get_post` you are able to compare how the post is now, and how the post will be: if you don't like something, you can change it.

Let's code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'preserve_content_filtered', 999, 2 );

function preserve_content_filtered ( $data, $postarr ) {

    /* If this is not an update, we have nothing to do */
    if ( ! isset($postarr['ID']) || ! $postarr['ID'] ) return $data;

    /*
     * Do you want you filter per post_type?
     * You should, to prevent issues on post type like menu items.
     */
    if ( ! in_array( $data['post_type'], array( 'post', 'page' ) ) ) return $data;

    /* How post is now, before the update */
    $before = get_post( $postarr['ID'] ); 

    /* If content_filtered is already empty we have nothing to preserve */
    if ( empty( $before->post_content_filtered ) ) return $data;

    if ( empty( $data['post_content_filtered'] ) ) {
        /*
         * Hey! WordPress wants to clear our valuable post_content_filtered...
         * Let's prevent it!
         */
        $data['post_content_filtered'] = $before->post_content_filtered;
    }

    return $data;

}
```

There is a possible issue, where the previous function prevents **every** `post_content_filtered` cleaning. And if **you**, for any reason, want to clear it?

I've said that every WP post change is handled by `wp_update_post`, but you are not WordPress.

You can write a function like:

```
function reset_post_content_filtered( $postid ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
        "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET `post_content_filtered` = '' WHERE `ID` = %d", $postid
    ) );
}
```

Being a `$wpdb` query, it doesn't trigger our filter, so resetting is done with no problem, and everywhere in your code you need to reset `post_content_filtered`, you can call this function.

You can also create a metabox with a button 'Clear content filtered' and when this button is clicked just call your `reset_post_content_filtered` function, e.g. via Ajax.