# When does a function assigned to the content_filtered_edit_pre filter hook fire?

Tags: filters, hooks

I added a function to the filter hook tag `'content_filtered_edit_pre'`, but it doesn't seem to fire no matter what I do. I am also aware of `'content_edit_pre'`, but I am curious as to when this filter hook is called. The following does not result in 'filtered ' being added to the front of my post when I open it in the edit screen, even after another filter has been run:

```
function test_of_content_filtered_edit_pre( $content, $post_id ) {
    return "filtered ".$content;
}
add_filter( 'content_filtered_edit_pre', 'test_of_content_filtered_edit_pre', 10, 2 );
```

The only documentation I can find on the Internet seems to be from the [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_filtered_edit_pre) or copies of it.

Comment: The [`Codex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_filtered_edit_pre) says 
`This filter runs in wp-admin when loading a post for editing.`

Comment: I saw that too - in the tests I ran though, only `'content_edit_pre'` ran at this time and not `'content_filtered_edit_pre'`. Would you be able to provide an example of an instance where it works for you?

Comment: What's the status of the question, is it still unsolved?

Comment: Your comment to look at the [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113387/when-is-the-post-content-filtered-column-in-database-cleared-by-wordpress/113701#113701) by @G.M helped a lot! Sorry, I've been away so didn't mark it as solved yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is activated within the [`sanitize_post_field()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_post_field) function:

> Calls 'edit_{$field}' and '{$field_no_prefix}_edit_pre' passing $value
>   and $post_id if $context is 'edit' and field name prefix is 'post_'.

So in the case of the `post_content_filtered` field, the filters are

```
edit_post_content_filtered
```

and

```
content_filtered_edit_pre
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I tried forcing a call to `sanitize_post_field()`, and still didn't get it to fire. May because it requires a 'post_' prefix. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: How did you test it? Try for example `echo sanitize_post_field( 'post_content_filtered', 'abc', 1 ,'edit' );`

Comment: ps. check for example this informative [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/113701/26350) by @G.M on how the field `post_content_filtered` is treated in `wp_updated_post()`. It's filtered but not saved, when you update your post, as far as I understand it.