# why wp_update_post cant update when value is empty?

Tags: wp-update-post

this runs successfully:

```
wp_update_post( array('ID' => $postid,  'post_content_filtered' => 'something' )   );
```

but this doesnt update:

```
wp_update_post( array('ID' => $postid,  'post_content_filtered' => '' )   );
```

why?

Comment: You will get the answer and a solution to fix this, with this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113387/when-is-the-post-content-filtered-column-in-database-cleared-by-wordpress